# How to prevent Pinterest "more like this" option on eCommerce website image hover from showing results when clicked

Tags: ssl-certificate, pinterest

Have come across an issue with Pinterest and their need to provide the little square next to the save button when hovering over an image. With a small eCommerce site, would like to prevent the user from getting results that are similar to the item once they click on the square after hovering over an image.

I know I can block Pinterest functionality entirely or I can block the hover action but I still want the user to be able to pin images from my site.

I've done some investigating and figured out that Amazon has this blocked. When you hover over any image on their site and then click the square, no results show. I also noticed that they are using a SSL certificate and then burying their images within a directory that contains that certificate.

So my question is, is there a way to block results coming up when the user clicks on the square? Through the use of a certain type of certificate or maybe a JavaScript encryption/other method? Without having get deep into the Pinterest API?

Included pictures to show what I am talking about.

[pinterest-more like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnApn.png)

[pinterest-image hover screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTyxm.png)